# C++ mutually dependent classes

Tags: c++

I have two classes which represent two different data types that can be converted back and forth. I want to have a constructor for each which takes an object of the other type so that I can more easily convert between the two, like so:

```
class A{
 public:
  A(B n){
    //Do stuff converting n to type A
  }
};

class B{
 public:
  B(A n){
    //Do stuff converting n to type B
  }
};
```

But it always fails to compile.

Comment: That's like the chicken'n'egg problem, there is no solution. You need a `B` to create an `A` and and `A` to create a `B`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you pass `B` by reference, you can use it as an incomplete type in `A`, with a forward declaration, like:

```
class B; // forward declaration

class A {
public:
    A() = default;
    A(B& n); // declare it here 
};

class B {
public:
    B() = default;
    B(A n) {
        //Do stuff converting n to type B
    }
};

A::A(B& n) // define it here, B is fully visible now
{
    //Do stuff converting n to type A
}

int main()
{
    A a;
    B b(a);
    A another(b);
}
```

Note that you'd also need default constructors for at least `A` or `B`, as otherwise you cannot create an `A` without a `B` or the other way around. We also only declared the constructor in `A`, but defined it after `B` is fully visible (thanks @MattMcNabb for the comment). In this way, you'd be able to use any member of `B` in the constructor, since at that point `B` is fully visible.

Comment: while not strictly necessary it is probably also a good idea to make the conversion constructors take a `B const&` and `A const&` since it is unlikely that the OP really wants to either copy the convertee nor modify it

Answer (score 1):

The problem you are having is a common for beginners of C++ (or C for that matter).

The issue is that the signature `A(B n)` is seen by the compiler before the declaration of `B` is seen.  But clearly, you cannot put `B` before `A` in the code, or you'd end up with the same type of situation.

This can be solved using forward declarations and references.  My suggested default approach to this would be to declare these two entities as

```
class B;

class A {
 public:
  A(const B& n) {
    // Do stuff converting n to type A
  }
};

class B {
 public:
  B(const A& n) {
    // Do stuff converting n to type B
  }
};
```